# Possible to read correctly a XML-RPC request with same methodName and different params?

Tags: java, xml, xml-rpc

I want to read an XML-RPC request with the same methodName but different parameters. For example, methodName being "configure" and the second parameter depends on the first parameter; if the first parameter is 1 the type of the second will be float and if the first parameter is 2 the second parameter will be int. I am using the XMLPC Helma library in Java.

Request 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>configure</methodName>
      <params>
         <param>
            <value><int>1</int></value>
         </param>
         <param>
            <value><int>4</int></value>
         </param>
      </params>
</methodCall>
```

Request 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>configure</methodName>
      <params>
         <param>
            <value><int>1</int></value>
         </param>
         <param>
            <value><float>5.32</float></value>
         </param>
      </params>
</methodCall>
```

The question arises when trying to process the requests as they have different types of parameters. How could I do it?